# Broadcast event in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angular.js

How can I refactor this code to be more clean?

```
  $scope.unreserve = function () {
    var params = {
      'wishlist_product_id' : product.wishlist_product_id
    };

    WishlistService.unreserve(params, function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('NotificationController.create', {type: 'success', message: 'Unreserve successfully'});
      } else  {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('NotificationController.create', {type: 'error', message: data.error_message});
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.createManualProduct = function () {
    var params = {};

    ProductService.addManualProduct(params, function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('NotificationController.create', {type: 'success', message: 'Unreserve successfully'});
      } else{
        $rootScope.$broadcast('NotificationController.create', {type: 'error', message: data.error_message});
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main changes I would make:

1. ProductService.addManualProduct seems to require a callback. A way that is more consistent with Angular, and with a number of benefits, would be to return a promise, so you can use it like:

   ```
   ProductService.addManualProduct(params).then(function() {
     // Do something
   });
   ```
2. Using `$rootScope` should be avoided if there is an alternative, as it's effectively global over the entire app. One way, would be to change the `$rootScope.$broadcast` to `$scope.emit`, which can be "picked up" by a directive on some parent element. So you could have a template like:

   ```
   <div notification-center>
     <div ng-controller="myController">
        <!-- Buttons here to create/unreserve -->
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   And in myController, `$emit` an event:

   ```
   $scope.$emit('notificationCenter::create', someData);
   ```

   Then in a `notificationCenter` directive's controller, you can listen to this

   ```
   {
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.$on('notificationCenter::create', function(e, data) {
          // Do something, like display the message
        });
      }
   }
   ```

   An alternative approach would be to have the notificationCenter directive inside the template controlled by myController, and then use `$scope.$broadcast` to send messages to it.

   The "clean" aspect of this is that you could potentially have separate areas of the app, with separate notification areas, if you wish.